# How to execute a PHP page with HTML in it?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am trying to create a online commenting system using php. This is my php page, with HTML in it. However, it is not executing as expected, with HTML elements being rendered, while php getting returned as garbage during execution. Am I missing something? Do I use .htaccess file to tell the compiler to execute it as purely a php file?

[Error image](https://s15.postimg.org/r593ht9i3/error.png)

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if (version_compare(phpversion(), "5.3.0", ">=")  == 1)
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
else
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); 

require_once('classes/CMySQL.php'); 

$sCode = '';
$iItemId = (int)$_GET['id'];
if ($iItemId) { // View item output
$aItemInfo = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->getRow("SELECT * FROM `s163_items` WHERE `id` = '{$iItemId}'"); // getting info about item from database
$sCode .= '<h1>'.$aItemInfo['title'].'</h1>';
$sCode .= '<h3>'.date('F j, Y', $aItemInfo['when']).'</h3>';
$sCode .= '<h2>Description:</h2>';
$sCode .= '<h3>'.$aItemInfo['description'].'</h3>';
$sCode .= '<h3><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">back</a></h3>';


$sComments = '';
$aComments = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->getAll("SELECT * FROM `s163_items_cmts`     WHERE `c_item_id` = '{$iItemId}' ORDER BY `c_when` DESC LIMIT 5");
foreach ($aComments as $i => $aCmtsInfo) {
    $sWhen = date('F j, Y H:i', $aCmtsInfo['c_when']);
    $sComments .= <<<EOF
<div class="comment" id="{$aCmtsInfo['c_id']}">
<p>Comment from {$aCmtsInfo['c_name']} <span>({$sWhen})</span>:</p>
<p>{$aCmtsInfo['c_text']}</p>
</div>
EOF;
}

ob_start();
?>
<div class="container" id="comments">
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitComment(e) {
        var sName = $('#name').val();
        var sText = $('#text').val();

        if (sName && sText) {
            $.post('comment.php', { name: sName, text: sText, id: <?=  $iItemId ?> }, 
                function(data){ 
                    if (data != '1') {
                      $('#comments_list').fadeOut(1000, function () { 
                        $(this).html(data);
                        $(this).fadeIn(1000); 
                      }); 
                    } else {
                      $('#comments_warning2').fadeIn(1000, function () { 
                        $(this).fadeOut(1000); 
                      }); 
                    }
                }
            );
        } else {
          $('#comments_warning1').fadeIn(1000, function () { 
            $(this).fadeOut(1000); 
          }); 
        }
    };
    </script>

    <div id="comments_warning1" style="display:none">Don`t forget to fill both fields (Name and Comment)</div>
    <div id="comments_warning2" style="display:none">You can post no more than one comment every 10 minutes (spam protection)</div>
    <form onsubmit="submitComment(this); return false;">
        <table>
            <tr><td class="label"><label>Your name: </label></td><td class="field"><input type="text" value="" title="Please enter your name" id="name" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="label"><label>Comment: </label></td><td class="field"><textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="label">&nbsp;</td><td class="field"><input type="submit" value="Post comment" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="comments_list"><?= $sComments ?></div>
  </div>
  <?
  $sCommentsBlock = ob_get_clean();

  } else {
  $sCode .= '<h1>List of items:</h1>';

 $aItems = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->getAll("SELECT * FROM `s163_items` ORDER by  `when` ASC"); // taking info about all items from database
    foreach ($aItems as $i => $aItemInfo) {
    $sCode .= '<h2><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?  id='.$aItemInfo['id'].'">'.$aItemInfo['title'].' item</a></h2>';
   }
  }
  ?>


  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Online commenting system</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <?= $sCode ?>
    </div>
    <?= $sCommentsBlock ?>
</body>
</html
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: What do you mean by "*php getting returned as garbage*"?

Comment: @RaxWeber, the page is getting rendered as HTML page, but bits and pieces of php code is getting displayed as text on the page.

Comment: Is `<?=` a correct tag? I have never seen it.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it is the PHP shorthand echo, which is equivalent to `<?php echo`.

Comment: @RaxWeber, to be clear, here is what error I am being getting. Image link: https://s15.postimg.org/r593ht9i3/error.png

Comment: @CodeNinja I can't open the link. Mind if you just add it to your post?

Comment: Is php module enabled on your server?

Comment: @starkeen I am using Eclipse with Apach Tomcat server. I am not sure how to enable PHP on Tomcat. Can you please tell me what I should do? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to replace your single quotes to double quotes. It seems your code does not read the end of a echo and the echo "keeps going". What I mean is for example, change this: `$sCode .= '<h3><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">back</a></h3>';`  to this: `$sCode .= "<h3><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>back</a></h3>";`

Comment: @Andreas, no effect even after adding double quotes in place of single quotes! :(

Answer (score 1):

Please check below update code and could you please is PHP install or not in your server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Online commenting system</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if (version_compare(phpversion(), "5.3.0", ">=") == 1)
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
        else
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

        require_once('classes/CMySQL.php');

        $sCode = '';
        $iItemId = (int) $_GET['id'];
        if ($iItemId) { // View item output
            $aItemInfo = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->getRow("SELECT * FROM `s163_items` WHERE `id` = '{$iItemId}'"); // getting info about item from database
            $sCode .= '<h1>' . $aItemInfo['title'] . '</h1>';
            $sCode .= '<h3>' . date('F j, Y', $aItemInfo['when']) . '</h3>';
            $sCode .= '<h2>Description:</h2>';
            $sCode .= '<h3>' . $aItemInfo['description'] . '</h3>';
            $sCode .= '<h3><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">back</a></h3>';


            $sComments = '';
            $aComments = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->getAll("SELECT * FROM `s163_items_cmts`     WHERE `c_item_id` = '{$iItemId}' ORDER BY `c_when` DESC LIMIT 5");
            foreach ($aComments as $i => $aCmtsInfo) {
                $sWhen = date('F j, Y H:i', $aCmtsInfo['c_when']);
                $sComments .= '<div class="comment" id="' . $aCmtsInfo['c_id'] . '">';
                $sComments .= '<p>Comment from ' . $aCmtsInfo['c_name'] . '<span>(' . $sWhen . ')</span>:</p>';
                $sComments .= '<p>' . $aCmtsInfo['c_text'] . '</p>';
                $sComments .= '</div>';
            }

            ob_start();
            ?>
            <div class="container" id="comments">
                <h2>Comments</h2>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function submitComment(e) {
                        var sName = $('#name').val();
                        var sText = $('#text').val();

                        if (sName && sText) {
                            $.post('comment.php', {name: sName, text: sText, id: <?= $iItemId ?>},
                            function(data) {
                                if (data != '1') {
                                    $('#comments_list').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                                        $(this).html(data);
                                        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    $('#comments_warning2').fadeIn(1000, function() {
                                        $(this).fadeOut(1000);
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            );
                        } else {
                            $('#comments_warning1').fadeIn(1000, function() {
                                $(this).fadeOut(1000);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    ;
                </script>

                <div id="comments_warning1" style="display:none">Don`t forget to fill both fields (Name and Comment)</div>
                <div id="comments_warning2" style="display:none">You can post no more than one comment every 10 minutes (spam protection)</div>
                <form onsubmit="submitComment(this);
                    return false;">
                    <table>
                        <tr><td class="label"><label>Your name: </label></td><td class="field"><input type="text" value="" title="Please enter your name" id="name" /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="label"><label>Comment: </label></td><td class="field"><textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea></td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="label">&nbsp;</td><td class="field"><input type="submit" value="Post comment" /></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
                <div id="comments_list"><?= $sComments ?></div>
            </div>
            <?
            $sCommentsBlock = ob_get_clean();
        } else {
            $sCode .= '<h1>List of items:</h1>';

            $aItems = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->getAll("SELECT * FROM `s163_items` ORDER by  `when` ASC"); // taking info about all items from database
            foreach ($aItems as $i => $aItemInfo) {
                $sCode .= '<h2><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?  id=' . $aItemInfo['id'] . '">' . $aItemInfo['title'] . ' item</a></h2>';
            }
        }
        ?>



        <div class="container">
            <?= $sCode ?>
        </div>
        <?= $sCommentsBlock ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Vishal, I have already tried adding the php snippet in the HTML body, but it is still not working. To clarify what error I am being thrown, here is the image link: https://s15.postimg.org/r593ht9i3/error.png

Comment: I think php not install/configure properly because php code not execute just render with html . Can I have access this page please share url.

Comment: Once more question please let me know file ext. also is .php or .html

Comment: I am using Eclipse with Apache Tomcat server. I am not sure how to enable PHP on Tomcat. Can you please tell me what I should do? Thanks!

Comment: The file extension is .php

Comment: I suggest to please use lamp server for linux system and xampp for windows. to run php file. below support link of eclips to run php code http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/running_php_web_pages.htm http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/running_php_web_pages.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `<?php` start tag. It is missing `<`.